# Which DOM elements cannot accept an id?

Tags: html, dom

I'm reading this [basic tutorial on `canvas` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Basic_usage). The `(almost)` in the following sentence caught my eye:

> The id attribute isn't specific to the  element but is one of the default HTML attributes which can be applied to (almost) every HTML element

Which html elements cannot accept an id?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In **HTML5**, the `id` attribute is a [global attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#global-attributes) and can be specified on **any** element.

---

If you look through the [Document Type Declaration for **HTML4**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html), you can find the elements which do not have `%attrs;` defined in their attribute list to indicate they do not support the `id` attribute. Those included are near the bottom in the "Document Head" section: `HEAD`, `TITLE`, `BASE`, `META`, `STYLE`, `SCRIPT`, and `HTML`.

Note that although the `PARAM` element does not include the `%attrs;` declaration in its attribute list, it does explicitly allow the `id` attribute itself in that list.

```
<!ATTLIST PARAM
  id          ID             #IMPLIED  -- document-wide unique id --
  name        CDATA          #REQUIRED -- property name --
  value       CDATA          #IMPLIED  -- property value --
  valuetype   (DATA|REF|OBJECT) DATA   -- How to interpret value --
  type        %ContentType;  #IMPLIED  -- content type for value
                                      when valuetype=ref --
  >
```

Answer (score 14):

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp) (yes, I know...) :

> Note: The id attribute is not valid in: `<base>`, `<head>`, `<html>`,
>   `<meta>`, `<param>`, `<script>`, `<style>`, and `<title>`.

Note that this is only valid for HTML4 but that explains the "almost" of the tutorial.

As others have pointed out, HTML5 accepts id on all elements.

Comment: This is the only answer I've ever upvoted which contains w3schools.

Comment: "The HTML5 specification states that global attributes may be specified on all HTML elements, even those not specified by HTML5." https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Global_attributes

Comment: Things like jQuery Templates (and some other js templating solutions) require IDs to be on `<script>` tags. Valid or not, they behave as expected.

Comment: Many things are wrong, and many things good. But we can't discuss it there. Look for the (biased) w3fools if you like.

Comment: w3schools gets a lot of hate because they pwned the W3C in terms of SEO, and because they don't always adequately proofread their stuff to make sure it's correct.  Many of their articles are considered over-simplified, especially the ones that use string concatenation in SQL statements instead of parameters (making their examples vulnerable to SQL injection).

Comment: You might just make history, a "Nice Answer" with `w3schools` in it.

Comment: In this specific issue, w3school is wrong on two accounts: it does not specify that its statement applies to HTML 4.01 (not XHTML 1.0 or HTML5); and it incorrectly claims that `param` does not allow `id`, since it does even in HTML 4.01.

Answer (score 3):

It’s a bit surprising that they say this in the context of the `canvas` element, which is an HTML5 element. In HTML5, the `id` attribute is allowed for any element without exception. Earlier versions of HTML impose various limitations. HTML 4.01 excludes `base`, `head`, `html`, `meta`, `script`, `style`, and `title`, but XHTML 1.01 removes this restriction.